# locate command does not work on mac terminal

Tags: database, terminal.app, locate

I'm working on Mac (Catalina, 10.15.7) and want to use the `locate <...>`-command.
After typing `locate ...` it suggested me the following, which I did.

```
WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

After creating the database, I wanted to perform the `locate`-command.
This didn't work as expected. Instead this came up:

```
locate: locate database header corrupt, bigram char outside 0, 32-127: -1
```

What can I do to fix this? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to delete (or move) the locatedb file, e.g. `mv /var/db/locate.database /var/db/locate.database.backup` and then regenerate the database from scratch using `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`. You will need to use `sudo` for these commands:

`sudo mv /var/db/locate.database /var/db/locate.database.backup`

`sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly.

Comment: This solution also works when `locate.database` doesn't exist. In that case you can jump straight to step 2. Tested on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71).